# How to re-execute a file

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to re-execute a file's code within the program

`main.py`

```py
# Within the main.py
exec(open('PDM/Path2.py').read())
```

`PDM/Path2.py`

```py
# Within the file being read
import tkinter as tkin

class path2_wind:
  def __init__(self):
    self.path2 = tkin.Tk()
    self.path2.geometry('400x430')
    self.path2.title('PDM/Path_2')
    self.sight = tkin.PhotoImage(file='PDM/Path_2.Sight.png')
    self.back = tkin.Label(self.path2,image=self.sight)
    self.back.pack(side='top')
    self.frame = tkin.Frame(self.path2)
    self.hello = tkin.Label(self.frame,text='Welcome User (Name Here)')
    self.back = tkin.Button(self.frame,text='Back',command = self.path2.destroy)
    self.frame.pack(side='top')
    self.hello.pack(side='left')
    self.back.pack(side='left')


    tkin.mainloop()

open = path2_wind()
```

The error displayed is `TypeError: 'path2_wind' object is not callable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have override the standard function `open()` by the line:

```py
open = path2_wind()
```

So when the following code is being executed again:

```
exec(open('PDM/Path2.py').read())
```

it raises the exception since `open` is not the standard function now.

Use other name instead of `open`, for example:

```py
win = path2_wind()
```

---

As @TheLizzard stated in the comment, it is better to use `import` instead of `exec()`:

**main.py**

```py
from PDM.Path2 import path2_wind

win = path2_wind()
...
```

**PDM/Path2.py**

```py
import tkinter as tkin

class path2_wind:
  def __init__(self):
    self.path2 = tkin.Tk()
    self.path2.geometry('400x430')
    self.path2.title('PDM/Path_2')
    #self.sight = tkin.PhotoImage(file='PDM/Path_2.Sight.png')
    self.sight = tkin.PhotoImage(file='images/nier-a2.png')
    self.back = tkin.Label(self.path2,image=self.sight)
    self.back.pack(side='top')
    self.frame = tkin.Frame(self.path2)
    self.hello = tkin.Label(self.frame,text='Welcome User (Name Here)')
    self.back = tkin.Button(self.frame,text='Back',command = self.path2.destroy)
    self.frame.pack(side='top')
    self.hello.pack(side='left')
    self.back.pack(side='left')

    tkin.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  win = path2_wind()
```

Comment: Can you please add something about using `import` instead of `exec(open(...).read())` to your answer?